# Сортировка первой строки двумерного массива по возрастанию

Tags: c++

Не могу найти в интернете как отсортировать первую строку двухмерного массива по возрастанию, используя функцию `sort()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long n = 10;

    int A[n][n];
    int i, j, sum = 0, k = 0;

    cout << "Enter the matrix\n";

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            A[i][j]=rand()%10;
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";}
        cout << endl;
    }


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(i == j)
            {
                sum += A[i][i];
            }
        }
    cout<< endl << "Sum= " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long n = 10;

    int A[n][n];
    int i, j, sum = 0, k = 0;

    cout << "Enter the matrix\n";

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            A[i][j]=rand()%10;
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";}
        cout << endl;
    }
    sort(A[0], A[0] + n);
    cout<<"Отсортированная первая строка двухмерного массива:\n";
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout<<A[0][i]<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Тут мы в качестве параметра функции `sort` передаем указатель на первый элемент первой строки и на конец первой строки

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

`sort(A[0], A[0]+n);` и в C++ нельзя задавать размер массива неконстантной переменной. n должно быть const или constexpr

Comment: Куда я должен поставить эту строчку кода?